# finding an estimate for $y(x)$ accurate to the 10 decimal places

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

the solution to the IVP

$\frac{dy}{dx}=1-Ax^{A-1}y$ where $y(0) = 0$ is

$y(x) = e^{-x^A} \int_{0}^{x}e^{t^A}dt$. How can I find an estimate for $y(x)$ accurate to the 10 decimal places?

Comment: please check your equation, I think you are missing a equal sign somewhere.

Comment: i fixed it @MrYouMath

Comment: What is the range of $A$ ?

Comment: i think it is 6 @YvesDaoust

Comment: If you are looking for an approximate solution use the taylor series approach.

Comment: Could you demonstrate how that is done?

Comment: This integral can be expressed in terms of the "Exponential Integral" function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html, or the Incomplete Gamma function.You can find evaluation methods in Numerical Recipes.

Comment: You may also consider direct integration of the differential equation by numerical methods (Runge-Kutta).